# Can get to one guest webserver on VirtualBox, but not to another

Tags: virtualbox, webpack-dev-server

I have a VirtualBox setup with Arch Linux. I use it to run various tutorials on Node.js and Redux. The host OS is Windows 8.1. I've mapped guest port 8080 to host 8080. When I run a simple Node.js server on the VM I can access it from the host machine on this port, just as expected.

Now I need to try another test server (`webpack-dev-server`). I start it in VM and check that it works via `curl`, but when I try to access it from the host, it says the connection was reset by peer. `curl -v` shows a pretty standard log: it sends a header and then says `Recv failure`. So:

- one web server on VM works OK and is accessible via the mapped port;
- another web server on VM works OK on VM, but is not accessible via the mapped port.

What could be the cause?

I think it's something with VirtualBox, but just in case I label this with `webpack-dev-server` as well.